# IPhone unit testing, how to support asynchronous function invoking based on event bus pattern?

Tags: iphone, unit-testing, asynchronous

In my project the event communication uses event bus pattern, who will be response to manage all the request and response, it has been packaged into a library and upper layer app will invoke this library to communicate with outside.

Now in my unit testing I need to test whether these API work well or not for some cases, dues to the response is asynchronous, seems we need a method to handle it in unit testing. Hey guys, do you have any experience on how to implement such kind of issue?  Any idea and discussion will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

BTW:
1. We use the following model to send request and deal with response in block.

```
sendRequestWithTicket:ticket 
    successBlock: ^ (response*) {}
    failBlock: ^ (response*) {}
```

1. We use OCUnit as unit testing framework.

Answer (score 0):

Seems difficult to do it for unit testing, maybe workable for system integration testing.